# Reading property values in constructor using prefix

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

How to use the prefix in the below code?

Properties:

height.customer.feet=10

height.customer.eu.timezone=UTC

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "height.customer")
public class Customer {

    private final int age;

    private final String timezone;

    public Customer(int age, String timezone){
        this.age = age;
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }
}
```

Here i want to set the default value for both age and timezone. Default values are read from application.properties file. Can someone help me please?

I could use like below.

```
    @Value("${height.customer.age}")
    private final int age;

    @Value("${height.customer.eu.timezone}")
    private final String timezone;
```

But if i use like this, i may not able to use constructor injection

Comment: Why do you need constructor injection? Values age and timezone will be populated normally using '@ConfigurationProperties' or '@Value'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between the `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value` annotation. Check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2254). What you should be using is the `@PropertySource` annotation. If you use `@ConfigurationProperties` then you should have hierarchical properties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "height.customer")
public class Customer {

    private final int age;  // This maps to height.customer.age

    private final String timezone; // This does NOT map to height.customer.eu.timezone but maps to height.customer.timezone

    public Customer(int age, String timezone){
        this.age = age;
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }
}
```

Use the `@PropertySource` with this example

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath: demo.properties") // your properties file
public class Customer {

    @Value("${height.customer.age}")
    private final int age;

    @Value("${height.customer.eu.timezone}")
    private final String timezone;

    public Customer(int age, String timezone){
        this.age = age;
        this.timezone = timezone;
    }

    public Customer(){}
}
```

And there won't be a conflict with the existing constructor because, values injecting via `@PropertySource` will be default values. If you provide values in the constructor, these will get overridden.